# Bash script : Navigate within directory and read the value from text file

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, cp

I am trying to read a text file and then navigate inside the directory as per the first chars of the line i read from the file.

please check the script below.

```
 #!/bin/bash
            filename="/home/user/telestreamupload/test.txt"
            while read line
            do


name="$line"
        YEAR=$(echo $name | cut -c 1-4)
        MONTH=$(echo $name | cut -c 5-6)
        YM=${YEAR}-${MONTH}

        april="2017-04"
        if [ "$april" -eq "$YM"  ]; then
           cd /mnt/media/April 
        else
            cd /mnt/media/$YEAR/$MONTH
        fi
      cp $name.mxf /tmp
        done < "$filename"
```

but i am having this error with IF else statment and as well as the cp command

```
sh telestreamupload/on.sh 
telestreamupload/on.sh: 15: [: Illegal number: 2017-04
cp: cannot stat '/mnt/media/2017/2017-11/20171125-018'$'\r''.mxf': No such file or director
```

Comment: (1) use `=` not `-eq` for lexical (string) comparison (2) your `/home/user/telestreamupload/test.txt` file likely has Windows-style CR-LF line endings

Comment: @steeldriver-. thank you for the hint, it solved the issue,

i am still stuck with CP command, its not copying the files

Comment: Did you remove the CRs? either run the file through `dos2unix` or change `name=$line` to `name="${line%$'\r'}"` for example

Comment: @steeldriver, yes i did as you mentioned, The problem seems to be with $name.mxf , because $name=20171125-018 and in linux if we need to copy the file, we need to as well use the extension in my case that is `.mxf`
I need to somehow concanate `.mxf ` at the end

Comment: Well, `$name.mxf` *should* work (because `.` is not a legal character in bash variable names) however if you want to be sure, use `"${name}.mxf"`

Comment: @steeldriver, looks the problem was the input file,I created New file with Nano and paste the entries and then it works.

thank you for the help!